# Upload and store data to shiny

Tags: r, shiny, geojson

I am working on a RStudio `shiny` app that reads in a `geojson` file then creates a map using `leaflet`.

I take my `geojson` file, and put it in my */data* folder prior to publishing.

Overall, everything works great. I am consistently changing some polygons in my `geojson` file, so I overwrite the old file and load the new all within the `shiny` app using an actionButton.

Things work great on my local machine but when I publish the app and use it on the web, my map file doesn't overwrite.

Is there a permissions issue within RStudio `shiny`?

I have also looked into using Google drive or dropbox to load then rewrite the file and have not had any luck.

Comment: What service are you using to host the web application?